# General MySQL query compostion

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table like this one:
[image]

Is there a way to retrieve directly using a MySQL query an array with the total for each year of men and women for each country?

For example:

```
cittadinanza 1987 1988 1990 ...
Afghanistan  13   13   12   ...
Albania      22   20   19   ...
...          ..   ..   ..   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to GROUP BY country.

```
SELECT `citidinanza`, SUM(`1987`) as `1987`, SUM( `1988`) AS `1988` FROM `table`  GROUP BY `citidinanza`
```